# Is SAJAX dead? What to replace with?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, lamp, sajax

We use Sajax for adding small Ajax code to sites.  After running into a problem and doing some digging, it seems the library hasn't been updated since 2005.

I've appreciated Sajax for being lightweight, easy to use, and easy to install (just include the file in PHP).

So, on the LAMP stack, if you  have used Sajax before, what would you upgrade to?  Ease of use is key since some semi-programmer web developers use the code too.

I know a lot of people would say jQuery, but is that as simple as Sajax?

Comment: yes it is dead;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it is easier to use [`jQuery`.`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: './example.json',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    // Use data...
});

$.getJSON('./some.php', { q: 'thing' }).done(function (data) {
    // Use data...
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './api.php',
    data: {
        action: 'save',
        info: APP.getInfo(),
        token: APP.getToken()
    }
});
```

`jQuery` is a great tool with lots of [examples](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples) and [plugins](http://frontendbook.com/10-must-have-jquery-plugins-and-extensions/) that allow you to do some pretty amazing things!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds a lot like [xajax](http://www.xajax-project.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but Sajax is a PHP library and jQuery is a javascript library. Just felt like that distinction needs to be made.

At our company we use jQuery and I think it's absolutely fantastic. Wouldn't trade it for anything else. But I would advise you to try any of the other many javascript libraries (Prototype, MooTools, YUI) and find out which one works for you.

Comment: Sajax is an open source tool to make programming websites using the Ajax framework — also known as XMLHTTPRequest or remote scripting — as easy as possible. Sajax makes it easy to call PHP, Perl, Python, ASP or Cold Fusion functions from your webpages via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use S2ajax: http://github.com/Fusion/s2ajax/tree/master

I just finally got around to pushing it to Github :)

Comment: Is it still maintained?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for jQuery integration with PHP, there are some classes in the Zend Framework. See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.html

Comment: The link is dead. Is this lib still available on zf website?

Answer (score 0):

There is also my branch over at http://sajax.info/ it mainly just fixes the outstanding issues with 0.12 and focuses on speeding sajax up even more.

Comment: Is the link dead?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend jQuery. It's much more straight forward that Sajax, which tries to be both end points for you. Besides, it can get messy with output buffering sometimes.