# Is there a way to realtime detect if there's new record in database?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have MySQL database, and program in C# and winforms. It will run on few PC's over the lan network. I want to know if theres a way to check if theres changes in database without doing request each second.

Example:
Admin will delete record from database, on workers pc I want to refresh list automatically.

Comment: Dunno, on SQL Server you have `SqlDependency` which you can register to and alerts you to table changes.

Comment: @Charlieface i don't see something like that in my project but i found this [link](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency.html) do you think this could work?

Comment: You where not the first one to ask this: [Is there a way to 'listen' for a database event and update a page in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471879/is-there-a-way-to-listen-for-a-database-event-and-update-a-page-in-real-time)

Comment: @Luuk but it's for JavaScript

Comment: Sounds good, just check the performance implications on very large tables

Comment: @zcoder: And? It is also possible to do AJAX from Javascript... (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496128/is-sajax-dead-what-to-replace-with/601538))

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292906/sqldependency-on-a-mariadb-mysql-database/51293221

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about the performance of polling.  With a suitable `INDEX`, MySQL can handle 100 polls/second -- regardless of dataset size.

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the tentative `SELECT` to perform the "poll"; I may have further tips.

Also, let's see the admin's query that needs to 'trigger' the workers into action.  Surely the admin can do something simple to cause that.  Doing a checksum of a table is terribly heavyweight.

You should consider the admin action to be encoded in a Stored Procedure, thereby separating the polling mechanism from the admin action.

JavaScript can use AJAX to do an INSERT (or call a Stored proc).

This mantra may apply:  "Don't queue it, just do it."  That is, the admin/javascript action can call an application program (PHP/Java/VB/whatever) to actually *do* the action, no need for queuing.  (Please provide more details so we can discuss whether this might be the real solution.)